# C# Regular expression with HTML tag to Xamarin FormattedString

Tags: c#, html, regex, xamarin

I'm trying to show formatted label in Xamarin forms (never mind if you are not familiar, the issue is not dependant on this). Given a string which can contain any character and <b></b> tag, I need to create FormattedString object, which contains spans of text. For instance

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur &lt;b&gt;adipiscing elit&lt;/b&gt;. Integer imperdiet massa accumsan turpis ullamcorper tempor. &lt;b&gt;Cras eget erat quis mi sollicitudin vehicula.&lt;/b&gt; Sed ac risus mattis.
```

This text should be transformed into these spans

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
2. adipiscing elit
3. . Integer imperdiet massa accumsan turpis ullamcorper tempor.
4. Cras eget erat quis mi sollicitudin vehicula.
5. Sed ac risus mattis.

I'm using following regular expression

```
 private static Regex _formatterRegex = new Regex(@"(?<text>[^<>\\/]+)|(?<bold><b>(?<boldBody>[^<>\\/]*)<\\/b>)");
```

So I match either <b>SOME TEXT</b> or arbitrary text. The problem here is that 'b' of <b></b> tags is also matched. Have a look into matches

[image]

I need somehow to match arbitrary text only if it's not inside <b></b> tags, so my match collection will not contain b-s of the html tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give me a link? I also wouldn't like to use whole HTML parsing lib for parsing just one single tag. In any case I want to solve this with regex, so I need a regex solution.

Comment: I suggest reading about [*The Greatest Regex Trick Ever*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#allbutx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur &lt;b&gt;adipiscing elit&lt;/b&gt;. Integer imperdiet massa accumsan turpis ullamcorper tempor. &lt;b&gt;Cras eget erat quis mi sollicitudin vehicula.&lt;/b&gt; Sed ac risus mattis.";

var regex = new Regex("(?<text>.+?)(?:&.*?;.*?;|$)" );

var matches = regex.Matches( text );

foreach(Match m in matches ){
    Console.WriteLine( "|" + m.Groups["text"].Value.Trim() + "|" );
}
```

Produces:

```
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur|
|adipiscing elit|
|. Integer imperdiet massa accumsan turpis ullamcorper tempor.|
|Cras eget erat quis mi sollicitudin vehicula.|
|Sed ac risus mattis.|
```